# Generate impulse response confidence interval. Tsdyn package in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I want to generate the confidence intervals of a response impulse using the tsDyn package in R. I tried to use the following code but I think it is not right, I would appreciate if anyone has any recommendations. Thank you.

```
library(tsDyn)
library(boot)

set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(50), var2 = rnorm(50), rnorm(50))

fun_tvar <- function(data, sd =1){
  tvar <- TVAR(data, lag =2)
  irfs <- GIRF(tvar,shk = sd, replic = 10)
  list(ir_down = irfs[,3,1], ir_up = irfs[,3,2])
}

fc <- function(d, i){
  d2 <- d[i,]
  return(fun_tvar(d2))
}

boot1 <- boot(data3, fc, R=50)
boot1
```

Information about the GIRF function [here](https://github.com/MatthieuStigler/tsDyn_GIRF).